# Classes - unable to return elements, possibly incorrectly invoking class constructor

Tags: javascript

There are two classes, CounterList and Counter. There is an input field, and a button. A word "name" goes into the input field. When the button is pressed, the code below is responsible for creating a new instance of *Counter* with the typed name, pushing that instance into an initialized array *counters* in *CounterList*.

The render method of *CounterList* is supposed to return an unordereed list (ul) for which the direct child is

from the *Counter.render*

*Counter.render* creates an li element, with direct children span and button twice.

ie, when the button is pressed, the name typed is supposed to display with two buttons next to it(increment and decrement) and a counter.

The code I have so far displays nothing. I inserted console logs, but I can't pinpoint where it's going wrong, except that the constructor for *Counter* doesn't even use the name in the input field

```
    class CounterList {
  constructor(){
  this.counters = [];
  }
  addNewCounter(counter) {
    this.counters.push(new Counter());
  }
  render() {
    var ul  = $('<ul/>').appendTo('body');
    ul.append(Counter.render);
    return this.ul;
  }
}
var x = $("#new-counter-name").val();
class Counter {
  constructor(x) {
    this.name = x;
    this.count = 0;
  }
  decrement() {
    count--;
    renderPage();
  }
  increment() {
    count++;
    renderPage();
  }
  render() {

    var li = $('<li><span>'+this.name+'</span><button>'+this.decrement+'</button><span>'+this.count+'</span><button>'+this.increment+'</button></li>');
    return this.li;
  }
}
```

Comment: `var li` ... `return this.li` ... is not referring to the same variable

Comment: in other words, you set a value to `var li` (or `var ul`)... then return the (undefined) `this.li` (or `this.ul`) - so `render()`, in both classes returns `undefined`

Comment: [There's a difference between local variables and object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572?javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object). Don't mix them up.